# Not able to POST to REST API

Tags: android, spring, security, rest

Today I'm making my first attempt of sending a POST request with a JSON to save some data, and I'm not being able to do so.
My app works by signing in, and then save, modify and delete data. It's already done in iOS, but since I'm new to Android, I'm not sure how to do it.
Here's my POST function:

```
public String POST(String targetURL, String urlParameters, String user, String pwd) {
        URL url;
        String u = targetURL;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            // Create connection
            // u=URLEncoder.encode(u, "UTF-8");
            url = new URL(u);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // cambiarlo luego al usuario q esta logeado
            String login = user + ":" + pwd;
            String encoding = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(login)));

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "plain/text");// hace q sirva con el string de json

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(120000);
            // Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            this.setResponseCode(connection.getResponseCode());
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

The method above is executed with Asynctask, and even if I use it to Login using Spring security, it works, and even I can save for internal usage the username, password, and secret token.
I dunno if I need to put the token in a header or something, because I already did that, with no positive results.
I'm supposing that the only permission I need to execute this is the internet one, so in my manifest file I specified that permission.
I'm going crazy with this issue, please help!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys, I'm kinda new to this way of asking, and also, not an English native speaker :P
The output I receive after sending the request, is the HTML of the page that handles logging in into the web app... I need like a json response or something like that to make sure the request was saved correctly

Comment: Could you be more clear explaining the problem? What error are you receiving? please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: String urlParameters. We dont know the content which you are gonna write to the output stream. It has to be specially formatted. Please show.

Comment: You could try enabling logging on the server and see the where does the processing stop. i.e. is it a Bad Request or anything?

Comment: Is not a bad request, it's just that I get the HTML as a response, not a json o something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Try handling your cookies

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

This should be a singleton.

Comment: Basically handle you `J_SESSIONID` cookies  so that you have a valid connection.